# CSV output includes unwanted header info

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I am using the script below to create *.csv files.
The output of lines 5 and 6 are correct.
It is also including other information in lines 1-4 and 8-10.
This information is from the header and footer of my page.

Any suggestions how to prevent this information from being included?

[image]

```
<?php
$csv_output .= $lang['klant'].';';
$i++;

$csv_output .= $lang['klant_ref'].';';
$i++;

$csv_output .= $lang['pos'].';';
$i++;

$csv_output .= $lang['aantal'].';';
$i++;

$csv_output .= $lang['dikte'].';';
$i++;

$csv_output .= $lang['kwaliteit'].';';
$i++;

$csv_output .= "\n";

for ($j = 0; $j <= $aantal_regels; $j++)
{
    $csv_output .= $klantnaam.';';
    $csv_output .= $klant_ref.';';
    $csv_output .= $posno[$j].';';
    $csv_output .= $aantal[$j].';';
    $csv_output .= $dikte[$j].';';
    $csv_output .= $kwaliteit[$j].';';
    $csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = $file;

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$lang['lijst_dxf']." ".$dossier_nr." ".$klantnaam." ".$klant_ref.".csv");

print $csv_output;
?>
```

Comment: Try to use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: You should use separate page to do this action. If required use query string to pass parameter on that page. The issue comes because HTML content are present in this page.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for a different solution Kuldeep. Then I will go with a different page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your $csv_output you need to delete the html content but here quick solution :

```
...$csv_output =str_replace(array('<link rel="stlesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/style.css"></script>','<style typ }</style>',"<div id='wrap'>",'<div class="footer_popup">','<img src="images/torza_logo_t.png"/>','</div></div>')
                    ,array('','','','','',''),$csv_output);
```

```
....$filename = $file;

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$lang['lijst_dxf']." ".$dossier_nr." ".$klantnaam." ".$klant_ref.".csv");

print $csv_output;
?>
```